# Xarray add (as in sum) two rows along same dimension but at different coordinate value

Tags: python, addition, python-xarray

I have used xarray to create two different DataArrays with the same dimensions and coordinates. However I want to add two different coordinates in one of these dimensions. I'm trying to add coordinate 'a' to coordinate 'b' in dimension 'x'. There is an easy workaround if these are the only dimensions of my matrix but more complicated if I have more dimensions and I want to keep the normal xarray behaviour for the other dimensions. Please see the example below that fails on the last line. I know how to manually fix this in numpy but the beauty of xarray is that I shouldn't have to.

Does xarray allow an easy solution for this kind of operation?

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# create simple DataArray M and N to show what I would like to do
M = xr.DataArray([1, 2], dims="x",coords={'x':['a','b']})
N = xr.DataArray([3, 4], dims="x",coords={'x':['a','b']})

print(M.sel(x='a')+N.sel(x='b'))  # this will NOT give me the value 
print(M.sel(x='a').values+N.sel(x='b').values) # this will give me the value


# create a more complex DataArray M and N to show what the challenge
m = np.arange(3*2*4)
m = m.reshape(3,2,4)
n = np.arange(4*2*3)
n = n.reshape(4,2,3)
M = xr.DataArray(m, dims=['z1',"x","z2"],coords={'x':['a','b']})
N = xr.DataArray(n, dims=["z2",'x','z1'],coords={'x':['a','b']})

print(M.sel(x='a')+N.sel(x='b'))  # this will NOT give me the value 
print(M.sel(x='a').values+N.sel(x='b').values) # this will result in an error
```

Comment: Did you read the error message of the last line? You're trying to add two differently shaped arrays together (3,4) versus (4,3). If you tranpose, it works: ``print(M.sel(x='a').values+N.sel(x='b').values.T)``

Comment: At any rate, I don't think you're doing this right way. The whole point of coordinates is figuring out which values **should** be added -- points with different coordinates are **not** the same points: that's the whole point of Xarray! Let's take a step back: what data are you working with, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @HuiteBootsma. I understood the error message. I actually created the arrays in such a way to create this error to show that my solution works for simple arrays but not for more complex ones.

Comment: @HuiteBootsma. I also understand that they are not the same points but in my case it makes sense to add them. I have a matrix that contains the 6 degrees of freedom in motion, velocity and acceleration of a body. I want to calculate the apparent acceleration by ax_apparent = ax+sin(roty)*gravity. In which ax is the acceleration in x direction and roty is the rotation of the body over the y-axis. Gravity works in Z-dir.

Comment: @HuiteBootsma is right : if your subsets (ie M.sel(x="a") and N.sel(x="b") do not have the same shape, you can't expect the arrays to be summed. I think the error lies in the construction of your "more complex" datarrays. What value do you expect at the end ?

Comment: @Hoogendijk what is the anticipated output for the last line?

Comment: Does passing `drop='True'` to your `.sel` calls do the trick?